# How to plot (correctly) lineplot from pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I'm plotting a lineplot from a pandas dataframe. However the labels are overlapped on the right side of the X axis instead of to the relative point mark on the line. What is missing?

Here the full code and the pic

```
#importing pandas package
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import seaborn as sns
# making data frame from csv file
dataset = pd.read_csv('curve.csv.csv')

df = pd.DataFrame(dataset.sort_values('Split')[['Split', 'Score']]) 
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

print(df)



ax = df.plot.line(x='Split',y='Score',color='green',marker=".")
ax.set_xlim((0, 1))
ax.grid(True)
# set the tick marks for x axis
ax.set_xticks(df.Score)
ax.set_xticklabels(['.005','.010','.015','.020','.040','.060','.080','1','15','20','25','30','35','40','45','50','55','60'
                    ,'65','70','75','80','85','90','95'])

ax.grid(True, linestyle='-.')
ax.tick_params(labelcolor='r', labelsize='medium', width=3)

plt.show()
```

[image: Image_plot]

My desired output would be to have all the labels on the X axis aligned to the relative marker point on the line.

Comment: `ax.set_xticklabels(['.005',...`What happens when I convert a string to a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using the y-values (`df.Score`) as the positions of your x-ticks.

I assume you meant

`ax.set_xticks(df['Split'])`